# Retrieving Azure Queue message length in C#

Tags: azure, azure-storage-queues

I noticed CloudQueue.ApproximateMessageCount would return the number of messages including the expired ones. This is probably a bug. Is there any way to see how many messages are in the queue?

Answer (score 1):

So after doing some digging around I think I found the behavior you're talking about. From what I can tell the messages are still in the queue when they expire but aren't retrievable. They seem to remain in there for a short period of time and then are cleared out.

If I had to guess it may be similar to a storage bus queue in that expired messages are moved to some sort of dead letter queue. Except with storage queues you can't access the dead letter queue and the dead letter queue is automatically cleared after some period of time.

I'll update this answer if I find more.

**Edit**

I confirmed the behavior. It seems expired messages remain in the queue but you can't interact with them. They disappear eventually without intervention it appears.

Comment: Would you mind sharing the link in your answer where you read this? Thanks!

Comment: @GauravMantri the link is the answer now. No problem!

Comment: Thanks! However the documentation link you posted is for Azure Service Bus Queue while the question is for Azure Storage Queue :).

Comment: @GauravMantri I updated my answer significantly after doing some experimenting on my own. I'll update if I find anything else out

Comment: There is an option to automatically move the expried message to the deadletter queue

Comment: @Thomas can you provide the documentation? I'm really curious about the behavior

Comment: @Casey, if you create your queue from the code(C#), you can specifiy the EnableDeadLetteringOnMessageExpiration option (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.queuedescription.enabledeadletteringonmessageexpiration.aspx) Otherwise the option is available through the portal when you create the queue

Comment: @Thomas that's part of the service bus queue api. That property works for the storage queue as well? So my theory is correct that the storage queue utilizes a dead letter queue that isn't transparent to the user?

Comment: @Casey, sorry I though it was for servicebus queue. so sorry .. Anyway I ll look at your problem.

Comment: No worries. The behavior differences between the service bus queue and the storage queue are a little confusing!